# Unhandled promise rejection when navigating from one screen to another

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to navigate from Mtag screen to recharge screen but I am facing error unhandled promise rejection. I use `this.props.navigation.navigate('recharge)` but did not succeed. Basically I listened to a response from API and when the response is 200, alert box is displayed and screen moves to the next screen. The response is shown but moving screen to next gives me error. Any fixes?

> TypeError: Undefined is not an object

[image: Error]

```js
//THIS IS MAINAPP.JS 
    import React from 'react';  
    import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';  
    import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';  
    import mtag from './screens/mtag';
    import recharge from './screens/recharge';
      

      
    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(  
        {  
            Mtag: mtag,  
            Recharge: recharge  
        },  
        {  
            initialRouteName: "Mtag"  
        }  
    );  
      
    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);  
    export default class App extends React.Component {  
        render() {  
            return <AppContainer />;  
        }  
    }  

    //THIS IS MY mtag.js 
    //I WANT TO NAVIGATE FROM THIS SCREEN TO ANOTHER AFTER TAKING RESPONSE FROM API
    import React , {useState} from 'react';
    import {
      StyleSheet,Text,Keyboard,StatusBar, ListView
    } from 'react-native';
    import {Container,Header,Input,Label,Content,Title,Card,CardItem,Button,Body} from 'native-base';
    import {createStackNavigator , createAppContainer , withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
    //import recharge from './screens/recharge';



    const mtag: () => React$Node = () => {

      //const [email,setEmail] = useState();
      // const [password,setPassword] = useState();
      const [mtag_id,setmtag_id] = useState();
      const [token,setToken] = useState();
      const [balance,getBalance] = useState();

      validateUser = async()=>{
        //alert(mtag_id);
        await fetch('http://SERVER_API/api/v1/user/login'
        ,{
          method:'POST',
          headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({"email":'ABC@YAHOO,COM',"password": 'ABC123'}),
          
        }).then(loginres => loginres.json())
        .then(loginresData =>{
          
          //alert(resData.token);
          if(loginresData.status == '200')
          {
            //alert('OK')
            //alert(resData.token)
           
           fetch('http://SERVER_API/api/v1/recharge/getInfo'
           ,{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': loginresData.token,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({"mtag_id": mtag_id}),      
        }).then(infores => infores.json())

          .then(inforesData=> {
            

            if(inforesData.status == '200'){
             
              alert(inforesData.status)
              this.props.navigation.navigate('recharge'); 

            }
            else{
              alert(inforesData.status)
            }
           
            console.log(inforesData);

          });
          }
     
          else
          {
            alert(loginresData.status);
            
          }
          console.log(loginresData);
        });
      }

      return (
        <>
          <Container>
            <Content>
              
              <CardItem header>
                <Text style ={styles.heading}>M-Tag Recharge</Text>
              </CardItem>

              <CardItem>
                <Input placeholder = "M-Tag ID" style={styles.input}
                value = {mtag_id} onChangeText={(value) => setmtag_id(value)}
                keyboardType = 'numeric'
                maxLength = {8}
                />
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem>
                <Body>
                <Button primary block onPress = {validateUser}>
                  <Text style = {styles.btn}>Recharge</Text>
                  
                  
                </Button>
                </Body>
              </CardItem>
            </Content>
          </Container>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could not use `this` keyword in hooks. simply use

```
props.navigation.navigate('recharge');
```

You also missed to use `.catch` in your validateUser function. `.then` is successor response, `.catch` is  rejected response.Replace your validateUser function with code given below.

```
 validateUser = async () => {
    //alert(mtag_id);
    await fetch('http://SERVER_API/api/v1/user/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({email: 'ABC@YAHOO,COM', password: 'ABC123'}),
    })
      .then(loginresData => {
        //alert(resData.token);
        if (loginresData.status == '200') {
          //alert('OK')
          //alert(resData.token)
      fetch('http://SERVER_API/api/v1/recharge/getInfo', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: loginresData.token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({mtag_id: mtag_id}),
      })
        .then(infores => infores.json())

        .then(inforesData => {
          if (inforesData.status == '200') {
            alert(inforesData.status);
            props.navigation.navigate('recharge');
          } else {
            alert(inforesData.status);
          }

          console.log(inforesData);
        });
    } else {
      alert(loginresData.status);
    }
    console.log(loginresData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.warn(error);
  });
  };
```

Comment: Does it work by removing `this` word from `this.props.navigation.navigate('recharge');` ?